# Avoid scientific notation with doubles in VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on this project, in Visual Basic:

```
   Sub Main()
           Dim i As Integer, j As Double
           i = 1
           Dim fileReader =
               My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\text.txt")
           For i = 1 To 3
               Dim stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
               j = j + CDbl(stringReader)
           Next
           Debug.Print(j)
```

End Sub

Which is supposed to read the first three lines of a text file containing:

37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629

Now when these numbers are added up, and the result is printed, it gives me scientific notation, so here is my question:

Is there a way I can make the program write the whole number without scientific notation, AND all the significant figures, I seem to get a problem where past 10 ~ 12 digits it's just all 0.

I know similar questions have been asked but I can't seem to find an answer to apply to my case, so I'm sorry if it is a duplicate.

Comment: A `Double` can only hold about 16 significant digits. If you need to handle more than that, you can use `Decimal` which can hold 28. If 28 isn't enough you should look at [System.Numerics.BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this. This will avoid `E` exponential format of numbers.

```
YourNumber.ToString(".################") 'No of digits = No of hashes #
```